# Compare Two .xlsx workbooks and print differences into a 3. workbook in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, printing, xlsx

I have two workbooks that needs to be compared and then print the differences into a 3. workbook. There is only one worksheet in each. for now, I user pandas to compare and print the result into the command line.
I'm very new to Python and do not know much yet.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('DNS_Master_List.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('CopyList.xlsx')
difference = df1[df1!=df2]
print (difference)
```

Comment: OK, so what is problem? How write output to excel? Can you add some data sample for better explain what need? Thanks.

Comment: Is possible write files as text? Because if pics, impossible copy :(

Comment: Added an example. you see there are missing text in some of the cells and I need to print a list of where changes anre applied

Comment: Yes, so your solution does not work? Or some error?

Comment: No it the solution works, I only need to print to a text not to command line.

Comment: `difference.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)` ?

Comment: I get the follwoing: AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\zipfile.py", line 1009, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'compare.xlsx'

Comment: Hmmm, it is another problem, maye need set some permissions ? Really hard problem :(

Comment: Now it works, I changed the index to true and saved the compare list into another directory. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not to print the difference, but to save the difference to an Excel file. For that, one might use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas-dataframe-to-excel).

Considering one wants to save the row names, one needs to pass `index=True`

```
difference.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=True)
```